Which statement is not a mistake that Reina has made?

"A survey done at a certain high school found that any student who liked tennis also liked swimming. They also found that students only liked swimming if they could swim."
Reina: If 30 students from the high school can swim, then 30 students from the school also like tennis.
If the quoted paragraph above is true, which of the following is NOT a mistake that Reina has made?

a. Some people may like tennis only because they like swimming
b. Some people may not like swimming even though they can swim
c. Some people may not like any sport but swimming
d. Some people may not like tennis even though they can swim


I got option d as the answer, because if you told Reina about option d statement, she would disagree, hence that option does not fall under the mistake Reina has made/assumed.
Am I wrong to think this?

The claim made by $d$ is true...nothing in the problem statement tells us that swimmers like tennis, only the other way round.  So if $R$ disagrees with it, she is making a mistake.

Using the framework of propositional logic, write $T$ for "likes tennis", $S$ for "likes swimming" and $C$ for "can swim". The first paragraph says that $T \to S$ and $S \to C$.
Reina concludes from this that $C \to T$, which does not follow (we only have $T \to C$).
Then, the options are:
a. Not completely straightforward to interpret, but this basically says $\neg(T \to C)$
b. $\neg(C \to S)$
c. $\neg(S \to T)$
d. $\neg(C \to T)$
It is then clear that the only incorrect option is a, because we do have $T \to C$ while none of the other implications are assumed to hold.



"A survey done at a certain high school found that any student who liked tennis also liked swimming. They also found that students only liked swimming if they could swim."
Reina: If 30 students from the high school can swim, then 30 students from the school also like tennis.
If the quoted paragraph above is true, which of the following is NOT a mistake that Reina has made?

a. Some people may like tennis only because they like swimming
b. Some people may not like swimming even though they can swim
c. Some people may not like any sport but swimming
d. Some people may not like tennis even though they can swim



The quoted paragraph tells us that Tennis is a subset of Swim and that Swim is a subset of Canswim, that is, $$T\subseteq S\subseteq C.$$ Observe that this is consistent with all of statements a to d.
Now, Reina's claim together with the quoted paragraph means that $$T=S=C.$$ This agrees with option a, and disagrees with statements b-d.
Hence, statements b-d, but not statement a, are Reina's mistakes.

I got option d as the answer, because if you told Reina about option d statement, she would disagree, hence that option does not fall under the mistake Reina has made.

Statement d contradicts neither the quoted paragraph nor Reina's claim, but does contradict the conjunction of the quoted paragraph and Reina's claim. Therefore, Reina is mistaken about this statement.
